# Check if checkbox value changed (checked or unchecked) then run function

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm a novice at jquery and was wondering how simple it would be to do the following.

I have a number of list items all containing dynamically pulled content that means the height of each list item might vary in height. I am running a jquery function that checks the height of each list item and then sets all list item to the height of the highest one. This all works fine on a $(window).resize(function() event, however I am looking for the function that resizes the list items to be triggered when a checkbox state is changed (either checked or unchecked). I'm struggling to work out how I might do this effectively.

Any help on this would be most appreciated.

Thanks
Jon

The code i'm using is as follows - not working with .change() event but working with   (window).resize event. Suggestions would be much appreciated - thanks in advance

```
var currentTallest = 0,
                currentRowStart = 0,
                rowDivs = new Array();

            function setConformingHeight(el, newHeight) {
                    // set the height to something new, but remember the original height in case things change
                    el.data("originalHeight", (el.data("originalHeight") == undefined) ? (el.height()) : (el.data("originalHeight")));
                    el.height(newHeight);
            }

            function getOriginalHeight(el) {
                    // if the height has changed, send the originalHeight
                    return (el.data("originalHeight") == undefined) ? (el.height()) : (el.data("originalHeight"));
            }

            function columnConform() {

                    // find the tallest element in the row, and set the heights of all of the elements to match it.
                    $('#results > li').each(function() {

                            // "caching"
                            var $el = $(this);

                            var topPosition = $el.position().top;

                            if (currentRowStart != topPosition) {

                                    // we just came to a new row.  Set all the heights on the completed row
                                    for(currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) setConformingHeight(rowDivs[currentDiv], currentTallest);

                                    // set the variables for the new row
                                    rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
                                    currentRowStart = topPosition;
                                    currentTallest = getOriginalHeight($el);
                                    rowDivs.push($el);

                            } else {

                                    // another div on the current row.  Add it to the list and check if it's taller
                                    rowDivs.push($el);
                                    currentTallest = (currentTallest < getOriginalHeight($el)) ? (getOriginalHeight($el)) : (currentTallest);

                            }
                            // do the last row
                            for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) setConformingHeight(rowDivs[currentDiv], currentTallest);

                    });

            }


           $('fieldset#filter[type="checkbox"]').change(function() { 
                    columnConform();

            });
```

Comment: if Thomas helped you in the way you expected, then accept his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `change` event to capture changes on a checkbox.

e.g. `$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){ /* resize logic in here */ });`

You can change the `input[type="checkbox"]` bit to narrow the scope.

If you want to select any checkbox with a class of `myChkbox` use: `$('.myChkbox')...` If you want to have it applied to all checkboxes within a specific form (id=myform) use: `$('form#myForm input[type="checkbox"]')...` etc...

Comment: `.change()` is the way to do this. However I don't think he wants to run this on all checkboxes ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help - I'd like to run the .change() event on check boxes with a specific fieldset ID is that possible?

Comment: Yeah, I realise, but I assume that changing the selector would be simple. I'll show you @jonjones ... i'll edit the question.

Comment: Sorry - yes, it is simple. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Don't be sorry! :) I assumed that because you were already using jquery you would already know about changing selectors and such. :)

Comment: Thanks again Thomas. I'm still having a few problems but will try and work out what the heck is going on :)

Comment: `$('fieldset#filter[type="checkbox"]').change(function() { ` this line is inevitably wrong. I assume you have a fieldset with an id="filter"? In which case you need `$('fieldset#filter input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {`

Comment: Yes, totally missed the input. It still doesn't work though - the content is being ajaxed in. I've also tried to use $('fieldset#filter input[type="checkbox"]').bind('change',function() { but it still doesn't seem to run the function.